# Tyrunt vs Aerodactyl

Tags: pokemon-x-y

So I just got these two Pokemon and can't decide at all which one I want to keep, they are both just so awesome sniff.

So I guess what it would come down to is... which one of these two are stronger?

Aerodactyl will eventually get his mega form, which I hear has the highest speed stat out of all the mega Pokemon, while Tyrunt will eventually evolve into Tyrantrum who has the highest defense out of all non-legendary poke. Immediatly... I find myself leaning more towards Tyrantrum since I personally find defense more useful. Also, since we can only mega evolve one Pokemon per battle, I feel that I won't really be using Aerodactyl's mega evolution as much as others on my team such as Charizard or Scizor.

So before I bury Areodactyl away in my PC forever, is Tyrantrum the better choice?

Answer (score 5):

Depends entirely on what you want to do with them. Do you need a physically defensive wall or a fast attacker? Tyrantrum and Aerodactyl aren't particularly comparable since they perform largely different roles.

Instead of thinking about which is better, since neither is *clearly* garbage (and neither is clearly super amazing if you're prepared for it), consider what you're going to do with it. Do you *need* the Mega Aerodactyl? Will you actually put the mega stone on it, or will you reserve that for someone else? Do you need a fast attacker, or a very defensive one? Does Dragon type or Flying type offer a resistance your team otherwise lacks? Note they both have a fairly significant number of type weaknesses.

Competitively speaking, [Aerodactyl fell out of favor in Black and White](http://www.smogon.com/bw/pokemon/aerodactyl/ou) but there isn't a proper Smogon analysis of either pokemon in XY because it's so new. The main fault for Aerodactyl has been Team Preview though, so it should still be fairly effective in matches against other random players less familiar with Aerodactyl's tricks.